# bashrc behaviour differs when opening a session or opening a terminal

Tags: linux, rhel, bashrc

I'm using RHEL 6.6.
I got a problem configuring my `.bashrc` file.
I have a `sudo su - dummy` followed by an `exit` in it.
When I open a terminal, the current user is changes to `dummy`. If I type `exit`, I go back to the previous user, then the `exit` of the `.bashrc` is executed and it closes the windows. Perfect.

But when I login, the `sudo su - dummy` is executed, then the following `exit` is executed right away and log me out right away...

Why does it behave like this ? Is there a workaround ?

Comment: I guess it depends on if bash runs as login shell or not.

Comment: @Encore: welcome on Unix.SE. Please make yourself acquainted with the Markdown syntax for formatting and skim over the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the `su - dummy` is executed when you login? 
Are you sure that your `.bashrc` is processed when you login? 
[`bash(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?bash) says,

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell
>   with the `--login` option,
>   it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. 
>   After reading that file,
>   it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order,
>   and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. 
>   The `--noprofile` option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

So you may need to put your `su - dummy` command into
whichever of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` you have.

Comment: Yes, the sudo su - dummy is executed. I wrote a log line right before and after it in the .bashrc. So yes, the .bashrc is processed too :)
I will try to move it to the file you said. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I tried to put my sudo su - dummy in the .bash_profile, wherever I put it, it doesn't have any effect.
Though, I put some logs in this file and I can see the file is executed.
I don't have a .bash_login or .profile.